# How did Jacob give his tithe as promised in Gen 28:22?

Tags: genesis, tithes

In [Gen 28:22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Gen%2028%3A22%20&version=NASB;WLC) Jacob vowed to give his tithe to God. (In the case of Abraham the Bible indicates that he gave his tithe *to Melchizedek*.) How then does the text indicate that Jacob gave his tithe to God, if there was no a priest at the time nor was there a Levite?

Comment: When you say 'the text' are you limiting the answer purely to the canon of scripture?